# Проблема с SIP-телефонией "Все линии заняты"

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, freepbx

Прошу помощи бьюсь уже который день, короче дали мне задание развернуть sip-ку,
все вроде готово и транки и маршрутизация, но мне выдается сообщение "Все линии заняты", а в логах ошибка:

> [2024-01-12 09:12:07] WARNING[2554] res_pjsip_outbound_registration.c:
> No response received from 'sip:ip' on registration attempt to
> 'sip:login@ip', retrying in '60'
>
> 10123 [2024-01-12 09:18:52] ERROR[2554] res_pjsip.c: Endpoint 'MCS':
> Could not create dialog to invalid URI 'MCS'. Is endpoint registered
> and reachable?     10124  [2024-01-12 09:18:52] ERROR[2554] chan_pjsip.c:
> Failed to create outgoing session to endpoint 'MCS'

Теперь новая фигня, при попытки поднять транк пишет request timeout
dump:
```ФГІЎ             q   пЄНeКј Э  Н     p…ВeНC   E`ЅК   @АЁXВXЗ(Д©МREGISTER sip:194.88.199.18 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 193.192.37.212:5160;branch=z9hG4bK6f91720b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:8018@194.88.199.18;tag=as335a50b6
To: sip:8018@194.88.199.18
Call-ID: 23d94b5b26eb743f36b4ca451dd843f1@127.0.0.1
CSeq: 189 REGISTER
Supported: replaces, timer
User-Agent: FPBX-15.0.23(16.24.1)
Expires: 120
Contact: sip:79595454640@193.192.37.212:5160
Content-Length: 0

```
   (  пЄНeпЄНeѕЅ Э  Н      Д­4Т’4   E`ЅК   ?}ФАЁXАЁX(Д©<ЭREGISTER sip:194.88.199.18 SIP/2.0
```

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 193.192.37.212:5160;branch=z9hG4bK6f91720b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:8018@194.88.199.18;tag=as335a50b6
To: sip:8018@194.88.199.18
Call-ID: 23d94b5b26eb743f36b4ca451dd843f1@127.0.0.1
CSeq: 189 REGISTER
Supported: replaces, timer
User-Agent: FPBX-15.0.23(16.24.1)
Expires: 120
Contact: sip:79595454640@193.192.37.212:5160
Content-Length: 0```

sip.conf:

````
;          Do NOT edit this file as it is auto-generated by FreePBX.             ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; For information on adding additional paramaters to this file, please visit the ;
; FreePBX.org wiki page, or ask on IRC. This file was created by the new FreePBX ;
; BMO - Big Module Object. Any similarity in naming with BMO from Adventure Time ;
; is totally deliberate.                                                         ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
[300]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=de9fb2fbe7691cf45901cff86cb20f37
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
defaultuser=
trustrpid=yes
user_eq_phone=no
sendrpid=pai
type=friend
session-timers=accept
nat=no
directmedia=nonat
port=5160
qualify=300
qualifyfreq=60
transport=udp
avpf=no
force_avp=no
icesupport=no
rtcp_mux=no
encryption=no
namedcallgroup=
namedpickupgroup=
dial=SIP/300
accountcode=
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callerid=Георгий <300>
recordonfeature=apprecord
recordofffeature=apprecord
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no

[79595454640]
username=login
type=peer
secret=pwd
qualify=yes
nat=no
insecure=port,invite
host=194.88.199.18
fromuser=8018
fromdomain=194.88.199.18
defaultuser=8018
context=from_trunk

[mcs]
username=login
type=peer
secret=pwd
qualify=yes
nat=no
insecure=invite,port
host=194.88.199.18
fromuser=8018
fromdomain=194.88.199.18
faxdetect=no
externip=193.192.37.212
localnet=192.168.88.0/255.255.255.0
localnet=192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 ;RFC 1918
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ;RFC 1918
localnet=172.16.0.0/12 ;RFC1918
localnet=169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0 ;Zeroconf
context=from-trunk```
````

Comment: AWS? В Asterisk SIP настройках NAT поле внешний IP что прописано?

Comment: моя выделенка стоит

Comment: есть у кого то варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Примечательно что MicroSip с настройками сервака провайдера звонится нормально

Comment: В общем проблема решилась следующим образом: я по простецки кинул провайдера в сервер минуя микротик, видимо проблема в НАТе была, но я с коллегами проверял НАТ корректно настроен

Answer (score 0):

Вырезка из старой методички

Возможно, проблема связана с неправильными настройками конфигурационных файлов, таких как sip.conf. Рекомендуется проверить настройки конфигурационных файлов и убедиться, что они правильно настроены для вашей сети и SIP-телефонии.

можно использовать команду "SIP SHOW PEERS" в командной строке (CLI) Asterisk. Эта команда отображает список всех пиров SIP и их текущий статус. Также можно использовать команду "SIP SHOW REGISTRY", чтобы проверить, зарегистрированы ли все SIP-клиенты успешно.

```
plaintext
[general]
context=default
allowguest=no
srvlookup=yes

[1000] ; Определение SIP-пользователя
type=friend
username=1000
secret=strongpassword
host=dynamic
context=internal ; Контекст обработки вызовов для этого пользователя
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[1001] ; Другой SIP-пользователь
type=friend
username=1001
secret=securepassword
host=dynamic
context=internal ; Контекст обработки вызовов для этого пользователя
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
```

Проблемы с настройкой sip.conf могут возникать из-за следующих причин:

```
Неправильное указание SIP ID перед @.
Неправильный пароль.
Неправильный тип подключения (например, вместо peer, используется user).
Неправильное указание порта SIP сигнализации.
Неправильное указание DNS имени или IP-адреса SIP-сервера.
Неправильное указание контекста для пользователей.
Неправильное указание кодеков.
Неправильное указание авторизации (alwaysauthreject = yes / no).
```

Для проверки настроек sip.conf, рекомендуется использовать команды Asterisk CLI:

```
sip show peers — отображение всех пиров SIP и их текущего состояния.
sip show registry — отображение всех SIP регистраций.
sip reload — перезагрузка модуля SIP после внесения изменений в файл sip.conf.
```

Конкретно, для проверки правильности настроек, стоит проверить следующие элементы:

```
Убедитесь, что SIP ID указаны верно и добавляются перед @.
Проверьте правильность установленных паролей.
Убедитесь, что типы подключения указаны верно (peer, user или friend).
Проверьте правильность указанных IP-адресов и DNS имён SIP-серверов.
Убедитесь, что контексты для пользователей указаны верно.
Проверьте правильность указанных кодеков.
Убедитесь, что настройки авторизации (alwaysauthreject) указаны верно.
```